# printing list items c#

Tags: c#, list, printing

Hi I'm trying to show a list in output but I'm having problems with printing my list items. here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace educationsystem
{
    public class student 
    {
        public string name { get;set;}
        public string lastname {get;set;}
        public long phone {get;set;}
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<student> Students = new List<student>();

            Students.Add(new student {
                name = "mahta",
                lastname = "sahabi",
                phone = 3244
            });

            Students.Add(new student { 
                name = "niki", 
                lastname = "fard", 
                phone = 5411 
            });

            Students.Add(new student { 
                name = "hana", 
                lastname = "alipoor", 
                phone = 6121 
            });

            foreach(student students in students)
                Console.WriteLine(name+" "+lastname+" "+phone);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I want the output to be like 
mahta sahabi 3244
niki fard 5411
. 
.
.
what should I do?

Comment: Your not referencing the 'student' when you print your output, just its properties. Also, you've written 'foreach(student students in students)'. Is that a typo and it should actually be 'student in students'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reference the student with its properties

```
foreach (var student in students)
{
    Console.Write(student.name + " " + student.lastname + " " + student.phone); 
}
```